# How to rerun javascript after a function is finished

Tags: javascript, refresh

Im starting to do some small functions and tweaks on websites with javascript, but whats really bothers me is that I dont know how to run the javascript again after a function has run?
For instance if I call a function onclick which adds a user to an array that is shown in my website, the new user wont be displayed until the page is refreshed?
How do I work around this?

EXAMPLE:

```
if (!localStorage.myStorage) {
     // CREATE LOCALSTORAGE
}else{
myArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.myStorage);
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)  {
        if(myArray[i].id === 1){
            $(".firstIdContainer").append("<p>" + myArray[i].userName + "</p>");
        }
        if(aUserLogin[i].id === 2) {
            $(".secondIdContainer").append("<p>" + myArray[i].userName + "</p>");
        }
    }
}
$(document).on("click", ".btnRegisterUser", function() {
     // ADD NEW USER TO LOCALSTORAGE
}
```

How do i make sure my new user i register will be shown immediately through my for loop displaying users.

Comment: That's why you group functionality into functions. After you added the user to array, call the function that generates the HTML from the array.

Answer (score 1):

Like:

```
if(!localStorage.myStorage){
  // CREATE LOCALSTORAGE
}
function doIt(){
  var myArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.myStorage);
    for(var i in myArray){
      var apd = '<p>' + myArray[i].userName + '</p>';
      if(myArray[i].id === 1){
        $(".firstIdContainer").append(apd);
      }
      else if(aUserLogin[i].id === 2) {
        $(".secondIdContainer").append(apd);
      }
    }
  }
}
doIt();
$('.btnRegisterUser').click(doIt);
```

Comment: Hmm, What function is yourFunction and what parameters?

Comment: The function that you've already run. It's name and those parameters are arbitrary. You'll have to show code if you want exact results.

Comment: I've added an example of my problem :-) the myArray i also uses throughout the rest of the code as a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a `contentUpdate` function that resets whatever is getting displayed and creates it again based on new variables (this would go at the bottom of a function to add the user, for example). The reason that variable changes aren't reflected in the DOM is that the DOM has no abstraction for how it was made; it's output, and it won't change itself based on what its input has done after it was put in.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to insert a new row into a table you don't need to refresh the page.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EGVz2/)

html:

```
<table id="usertable">
    <tr><td>user 1</td></tr>
</table>

<input id="newuser"></input>
<input id="adduser" type="submit"></input>
```

js:

```
var button = document.getElementById('adduser');

button.onclick = function(event) {


   var user = document.getElementById('newuser').value 

   //add the user to your array here

   //add a table row
   var table = document.getElementById('usertable');
   var row = table.insertRow(0);
   var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
   cell1.innerHTML = user;
   event.preventDefault();
}
```